# How to Switch Path ov rendereded Vehicle in three.js using YUKA library

Tags: three.js

how to switch vehicle path in y=three.js using YUKA library of already rendered vehicle.

```
  let currentPath;

  function switchVehiclePath(vehicle, newPath, targetPosition) {
    if (!vehicle || !newPath || !targetPosition) {
      console.error('Invalid arguments provided to switchVehiclePath');
      return;
    }
  
    // Remove the vehicle from the current path.
    if (currentPath[vehicle]) {
      currentPath[vehicle].remove(vehicle);
    }
  
    // Add the vehicle to the new path.
    newPath.add(vehicle);
  
    // Update the current path for the vehicle.
    currentPath[vehicle] = newPath;
  
    // Set the vehicle's target position to the specified position on the new path.
    vehicle.targetPosition = targetPosition;
  }
```

i  have tried several methods its was giving error then i tried this way now its not giving error neither changingpath

Comment: Do you mind showing in a small live example what you are trying to achieve? Use the following fiddle as a code template: https://jsfiddle.net/g3atw6k5/